# Windows developer license (permissions)

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I tried to set up a Windows Developer license on my computer, but it fails.

I am running Visual Studio 2012.

When I click Project -> Store -> "Acquire Developer License" It gives me an info dialog and says, "If you agree to these terms and want to install a developer license, click 'I agree'. The 'I agree' button has a Windows admin shield.

When I click that 'I agree' button and wait nothing happens.

My next attempt was to do this from the command line, so I brought up PowerShell and typed:

```
Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
```

And I get:

> Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration : You need administrator
>   privileges to acquire or remove a developer license.

So I right click Windows PowerShell and click "Run As Administrator" and wait ... and wait ... nothing happens.

I'm getting the feeling the Windows Store is not ready for prime time.

Comment: Windows Store is probably fine. Did you try running VS as an administrator before using "Project->Store->Acquire Developer License"? (Right-click the VS shortcut and choose "Run as Administrator".)

Comment: Thanks @Ken: when I try running VS as administrator it just goes away and VS doesn't start.

Comment: What does the Windows Event Log tell you? Do you have administrator credentials on your machine? What happens if you actually log in as Administrator and run VS?

Comment: I'm here because I tried it from the command line and got the admin privileges error. I'm interested in figuring out how to get around this particular problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I don't restart Windows 8 frequently enough, which @Ken helped me figure out.

Restarting fixed it.

Getting the license from VS was easy once I was able to run it as administrator.